# HTML node is not contained when I read the webpage using read html()

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am relatively new to scraping with R & have experience with R but almost no experience with html.

So when I tried to get the ratings of a menu of the following webpage: https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezepte/tomaten-kokos-dal
i noticed, that `xml2::read_html("https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezepte/tomaten-kokos-dal")` does not give me the exact output as I get when I investigate the Webpage using the developer tool on my web browser.
As the node I would like to scrape:

[image]

is not contained in:
`read_html("https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezepte/tomaten-kokos-dal")`
I can also use any possible node and not getting the right output-> (**Bewertung 4.8**).

I am totally confused. Does anyone have an idea why `read_html` doesn't provide the whole html content?

Best regards and thank you so much for your help!

+++++++++++

If needed, here is a more detailed approach how I do it:
When I run the read_html() in R I get the following output (when I go to the first h1 node):
[image]
This equals what i see in the developer tool in the browser:
[image]

But when i open div and one more time div, what I see in R and what I see in the browser is different:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site renders using Javascript. The html source code sends the browser a Javascript source file and the browser builds the html from it. A browser like Chrome can render the site, but R and the `xml2` package don't have such browser capabilities.

The Javascript file used to render the site seems to be near the bottom of the script:

```html
[3093] <!-- MAIN APP -->
[3094] <script src="/.resources/migusto/2.1.1-master-92-f8895ec/webresources/js/main.js"></script>
```

There are methods for scraping Javascript-rendered sites, usually using a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). Here's a resource that uses PhantomJs (one such headless browser) and R to scrape Javascript: [How to Scrape Data from a Javascript Website](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/12/how-to-scrape-data-from-a-javascript-website-with-r/)

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the answer, or let me know if there's anything I didn't answer.